# unmarshal a complex xml file using jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

how to unmarshal a complex xml file using java api jaxb.
I am Javacode as

```
File file = new File("config.xml");  
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Config.class);  

    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();  
    Config  que= (Config) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

but while unmarshiing this file I am getting an exception.

```
doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
```

xml file that I want to unmarshal is

```
<config>
  <module>
<name> File Reader</name>
<description> file reader using in process Id 1</description>
<ModuleParam>
<Param name = "file.size" value ="100"/>
<Param name = "file.process.name" value ="fileReader"/>
<Param name = "fileWriter" value ="fileWriter"/>
</ModuleParam>
</module>
<datasources>
<dataSource name ="driver" class="com.filereader.ReadFile.JdbcInsert"/>
    <param name ="driverClassName" value ="com.jdbc.FileInsert" />
</datasources>
</config>
```

Comment: Does your class `Config` have an `@XmlRootElement` annotation?

Comment: yes ,Config class marked as @XmlRootElement. again i am facing problem.

Comment: the xml is invalid. change `</module>` with `</Module>`

Comment: its a sample xml, here is typo error, please ignore it . I just edited

Comment: share your config.java file

Comment: @Ravi I dont know,  I am new to Jaxb can you please help on that , what are required to convert xml to java

Comment: @shiv you are using Config.class class and you are saying, you don't know ?